# How to through the gracenote playlist ident (eg: 0_12) get the name of the song

Tags: playlist, gracenote

I have a confused, I want to through the generation of playlist in the ident (eg: 0_11) to get the song name, what shoud I do and  those functions can be used. thank you!

Comment: can you please include the platform and language you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Collection Summaries in Gracenote Playlist do not store any metadata. The Collection Summary only stores the identifier for a piece of media that your application gives it. Playlists that are generated will only return these identifiers.

It is up to your application to use these identifiers to refer back to the media to do what you wish (in your case, to get the track name). Most media applications already have a media database of their own, so the identifier is normally a reference into the application's media store.

TL;DR;
You need to create a database that maps the Playlist identifiers to the song name.